# What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

The descriptions for the editing badges are:

> **Editor**: [First edit](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor)
>   **Strunk & White**: [Edited 80 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white)
>   **Copy Editor**: [Edited 500 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor)

Does "posts" include your own questions/answers, or are these badges just for edits to other people's stuff?

Other questions about how editor badge works:

- What if I edit only a question's tags, but not its body?
- What if I edit both a question's tags *and* its body?
- Do edits to Community Wiki posts count?
- Do edits to answers count?
- Do edits to tag wiki pages count?
- Do edits to comments count? (Moderators can edit other users' comments, even outside of the usual five minute window.)

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Also, what happens if you someone re-edits a post that you edited. Does that count towards the badge or not? In my opinion, it should still count.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

*What is included*

- community-wiki posts
- tag wikis and excerpts

*What is NOT included (only applies to Strunk & White and Copy Editor)*

- edits to your own posts
- edits to tags

To count for S&W/Copy Editor, the edit must cover the title, the body or both.

Comment: Is there way to see how many edits I have?

Comment: Does an edit that includes both tags and body editing count?

Comment: @vlad yes, as long as the body or title is edited, that's all that matters

Comment: @Asssaf: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/5117

Comment: Query edited to not specifically target S&W: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/5157/how-many-edits-have-I-made?UserId=40468

Comment: @Lazer: That assumes nobody else has edited the post since.

Comment: @Lazer : The query is wrong. It is looking only for records that are last edited by the user. A post that is edited by a user still contributes towards the S&W badge irrespective of whether he edited last or not.

Comment: What about rollbacks?

Comment: Plus it looks like that query has 100 edits as the limit for S&W, whereas I think the actual limit is 80.

Comment: Here's a much nicer query: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62091/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges

Comment: @AnnaLear `does not include edits to tags` **but** `tag wikis and excerpts are eligible`. Is editing tags different from editing the tag wiki ?

Comment: @AshRj "Edits to tags" = "changing what tags the question has"

Comment: @AnnaLear Oh! Ok, thanks.

Comment: What is the rationale for tag edits not counting toward Copy Editor? There is huge value to future visitors in making the tags proper.

Comment: @MuMind, thank you for your helpful query. Do you have any idea why there might be a discrepancy between the counts returned from your query and the counts shown on the Activity Dashboard?  For example, picking a random user who has done many edits: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2998271/har07?tab=activity -> has a count of 1063 on your query. Any idea what causes this difference in 6 edits?

Comment: @nick I just found a query someone else had posted. I'd ask the creator or last editor about discrepancies.

Answer (score 27):

Just to expand a bit more in detail, let me know if I've left anything out.

### What can I edit for the badge?

You can edit any normal questions or answers, including questions or answers which have been converted to community wikis. You can also edit tag wikis and their excerpts, which are both counted **separately** as edits.

### What edits do not count towards the badges?

- Edits made on your **own posts**.
- Edits which **only change tags**.
  In order for the edit to count, you *must* change something in either the body *or* the title. This can include changes to the tags as well, as long as one of the body or title gets edited with it.
- Multiple edits to the **same post**.
  Only the first edit to a single post will count.
- Posts which get **deleted** after your edit.
  The edit will only count as long as the post in question remains intact. If at any point it gets deleted, the count with decrement.
- Edits made on **comments**.
- **Actions** taken on the post.
  Since you are not actually editing anything, actions such as closing, deleting, rollbacks, and converting to community wiki do not count.

### Where can I view the number of edits I've made?

You can view the number of edits that currently count towards the badges in the [review panel](https://stackoverflow.com/review). Go into any one of the review tasks and hover over the progress bar located at the top and to the left of the tabs. The number at the left of your Copy Editor progress bar is the number of eligible edits you've made so far.

[image: Copy Editor badge progress]

If you suggest edits, **do not** trust the number of approved suggested edits that are listed on the suggested edit screen. This number is for *all* the suggested edits you have made, not particularly the ones that count towards the badge(s).

### What if my edit gets rolled back?

The edit you made remains completely intact for the post. Since it was an actual, physical edit that could in the future get rolled back too as well, it will still count towards your overall progress. Only the action of rolling back does not count.