# Reputation points for editing?

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits

Do you get reputation points for other users' posts that you've edited if they are up-voted after your edit?

Comment: Oh the chaos this would cause....

Comment: @chacha102 Agreed, it would be chaotic - I was curious though.

Comment: Sorry @Jon Seigel - No points for you!

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36574/let-me-reward-a-good-edit-on-my-question-answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, only the original author of the post gets reputation and badges for votes on them.

There was a suggestion a while back about being able to upvote *revisions*, but I think it was declined.