# Why did I get 2 rep points on dba.stackexchange for a question where I only added a tag?

Tags: support, edits

Despite [this statement on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41757/reputation-points-for-editing), I seem to have gotten 2 reputation points for editing a question.

Form https://dba.stackexchange.com/reputation I see that I got 2 rep points:

```
....
-- 2011-03-05 rep +7    = 910       
 2      1584 (5)
 16      866 (2)
-- 2011-03-06 rep +7    = 917
```

[here on dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/866/what-is-clustered-index) you see, that I only added a tag.

What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The other way to gain reputation is by suggesting edits to existing posts as a new registered user. Each edit will be peer reviewed, and if it is accepted, you will earn **+2** reputation. You can only earn a maximum of **+1000** total reputation through suggested edits, however.

From the [FAQ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) (this "suggested edits" thing is still fairly new).

Also (this might be the thing that's particularly confusing here, since you have >200 rep on dba) see [Retagging through suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78277/retagging-through-suggested-edits)

Comment: I still think this behaviour makes no sense...

Comment: @Jon why? He retagged a question. The edit got peer reviewed and approved, and gained him +2. What's the problem?

Comment: @Pekka: He's over the rep required for the retag privilege, so he didn't really need to go through the peer review process.

Comment: @Jon ah, I see.