# Editors point reward

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation points for editing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41757/reputation-points-for-editing)

Do we get rewards for improving someone else's answer?

I wanted to improve an answer recently, but I didnt want to be a jackass by creating a new answer that just stole an existing answer and just improved on it.

I should get some sort of points reward for the posts I modify. This would encourage me more to improve answers, which would improve the content of StackOverflow overall.

Comment: If you are < 2K rep and your edit is accepted, you will be awarded +2 rep.

Comment: you have 4K rep on SO and you dont know **edit** feature ?

Comment: I was saying like @ernest above he edited my question... if someone upvotes my question he should take some credits for it... as well as those who edit the answers when they are upvoted, I think it would encourage people to improve contents :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd If the OP means share in the upvotes as a result of the editing, yes. But I think he just means points for editing as such.

Comment: @MrLister I meant share, from then on ... or just the editor being credited points

Answer (score 0):

You can't give yourself rep (except by accepting and associating).

You get rep for accepted edits if you have less than 2000 rep. But this is because you need to be reviewed by at least 2 persons.

You can get three badges for editing. But the prime reason to edit should be to improve the site content.