# What if the author of the post could approve the edition by upvotes?

Tags: feature-request, edits, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let me reward a good edit on my question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36574/let-me-reward-a-good-edit-on-my-question-answer)

What if the author of the post could approve the editions by upvotes? With, possibly, a hidden comment?
It could work instead of "thanks for edition" in the thematic comments and make them more readable. 
Later, for collecting, say, 30, 200, or 1000 of such thanks, the editor could get badges for it: 
Accepted Editor, Valued editor, Favorite editor.

Comment: Were you waiting for someone to remove that rogue `<li>`? ;)

Comment: According to [Jeff answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36575/152859) on the dupe question, I don't see such thing happening any time soon.

Comment: Yes and to thank him for it so that he'll become the favorite editor... If seriously, I was trying to make a little space at the start of the paragraph. I hate paragraphs with even left side. But I have lost the tag that does it.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd The main point of *mine* post is to move "thank you for editing" comments somewhere out while allowing people to remain polite. And a weak instrument to support such change.

Comment: @Gangnus nothing wrong in "thanks for the edit" comment. This is better prize than badge to many people (myself included) and if someone think it's "noise" he'll flag the comment and it will be removed - no penalty to anyone, I believe thousands of comments are removed every day.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd I thought so, too. But I was said that it is bad to write thank you and it will be removed, edited off and downvoted and ... I am not sure, but may be a bullet at the wall will be the last measure.