# More badges for editing

Tags: discussion, badges, edits

[In this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/adding-incentive-for-editing), there is some discussion about added incentive for editing. And there I talk a little about adding more badges for editing related activities.

Currently we have

- **Cleanup** - First rollback (Bronze)
- **Editor** - First edit (Bronze)
- **Organizer** - First retag (Bronze)
- **Strunk & White** - 100 Edits (Silver)

I think there is a place for a few new editing badges maybe thinks like 100 retags and rollbacks and a **gold badge for editing.**

What do you think?

Comment: Look at the related questions...? -->

Comment: I swear is searched for similar questions. GRRR

Comment: I demand a badge for hand retagging 500 questions! @Jon would also I bet lol

Comment: @Earlz: My edit count might be integer-overflowing soon, just like Jon Skeet's rep.

Comment: @Mark: He *asked* that question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we should be encouraging more rollbacks: it's quite rare that they are necessary and it would just result in people rolling back good edits to get the badges.

Regarding the editing, often there is a rush to edit the formatting of questions within the first few minutes, oftern resulting in multiple people overwriting each other's changes. I'd rather encourage people to make more careful and thoughtful edits later than get even more people rushing at the start to fix formatting.

Can we find a different way to reward editing apart from edit as much as you can? Something that rewards the quality of the editing, not just the quantity. Tricky though...

Comment: Perhaps a badge for X times editing a post and changing 5-15% of the content. (or some other % number). That would try to target people cleaning up posts which would result in a small % number change.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/a-higher-level-strunk-white-badge-1000-edits-or-such) was solved on [2010-07-09](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99024/197593) by introducing the [Copy editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56397/197593) gold badge, awarded after 600 edits.