# Does retagging a question count as an edit for Strunk & White?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)

Does retagging a question count as an edit for the [Strunk and White badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does not count for the Strunk and White badge

Comment: I must admit I didn't think it did.

Comment: That's confirmed? Wow, then I definitely ought to have S&W on SO by now ... weird!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-strunk-white/445#445

Comment: Wait, so, is this answer actually incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't count towards the badge. Edits to your own posts and retagging are not counted towards the Strunk and White badge. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-strunk-white) by Jeff himself in meta. I don't know if the rules have changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.

In terms of the badge? not sure. Not sure if that's what you were asking, actually.