# Rollbacks and Strunk & White

Tags: support, edit-badges, badge-progress

Do rollbacks count as edits towards the Strunk & White badge?

Comment: I too want to know. Don't know why this question has not grabbed any attention.

Comment: *Related:* [How do I estimate Strunk & White progress?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39215/54262)

Comment: Related, but by no means a dupe: [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the rules are the same as those for [moving a post into community wiki mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60923/141911): In other words, only body edits count, not title edits, retags, or rollbacks.