# Which edit actions can move a post into Community Wiki mode?

Tags: support, edits, community-wiki, tags

Surprisingly, I couldn't find a straight answer to this.  It's not entirely clear in the [Community Wiki FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

There are (at least?) four different types of edit actions:

- Body edits
- Title edits
- Retags
- Rollbacks

And a few actions that show up in the history but aren't really "edits":

- Close/Reopen
- Delete/Undelete

The FAQ *seems* to indicate that only body edits are important as far as "wikification" is concerned, but I'm not sure if that's really correct or if I'm just interpreting the post too literally.

The FAQ also says that rollbacks don't *reverse* the calculations - fine, but are they considered to be *additional* edits or are they ignored?

Can anyone tell me which of these actually count toward the wikification of a post, and whether the rules are any different for owner edits vs. multiple editors?

Comment: Last I checked, rollbacks don't count.

Comment: Ok - get two other people to retag this: if it's still not CW, then retagging doesn't count.

Comment: Well, looks like retagging doesn't count.

Comment: Apparently not.  I'd try testing for rollbacks, but since the rollbacks would just be on retags, it might not be a very good test.  And there's still the whole title/close/delete thing.  Maybe I should just test this out on a sandbox post.

Comment: I don't think closing, by itself, will trigger CW status. However, dupe closing will have the Community User automatically edit the post body... so that may or may not impact it.

Comment: Closing will require a lot of people to do it multiple times, so I just skipped that portion and ran [this one](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/843/revisions) through 8 sets of closing/reopening for 16 elements in the revision history. No CW occurred. After I get some edits by other users, I'll see if duplicate closure will trigger CW.

Comment: Bear in mind that Meta may be a slightly biased test in that the thresholds here may be higher than on SOFU. I remember Jeff saying they're relaxed somewhat, although I don't recall if he said *how* relaxed.

Comment: Well, [this question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/843/a-testing-question-with-regards-to-mechanicalities-closed) went through 5 duplicate closings with 3 other users contributing post edits, so that seems to imply that the Community User does not cause CW status when closing as a duplicate.

Comment: [This no longer applies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is related to the old automatic community wiki triggers, which no longer exist today.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog Simply closing obsolete questions is baaad. It makes looking as if it would be off-topic, or bad. While they are not. I think asking the mods in a flag for a historical lock would be a better option. Or, the content could be edited to say, that yes once it was so, but now this is disabled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a list of the results obtained so far, looking at this question's history and also Grace Note's [test question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/843/revisions).  If anything is wrong or missing, please edit.

Edit actions:

- Body edits: **YES**
- Title edits: **NO**
- Retags: **NO**
- Rollbacks: **NO**

Moderation actions:

- Close/Reopen: **NO**
- Delete/Undelete: **NO**

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware it doesn't matter what type of "edit" it is. Any change to an answer or question content or title, which doesn't fall within the 5 minute threshold, counts toward the final conversion count.

The only exception I can think of would be retagging.

Comment: So retagging definitely doesn't count or you're not sure?  What about rolling back a retag?  I seem to remember retags not having the 5-minute grace period, so that could be important.

Comment: @Aarobot I am not sure, although I can't recall ever seeing a switch because of retags. Retags are instantly logged, and because the reputation limit is lower to be able to retag, I am making the assumption they would be excluded.