# What would be the criteria for rejecting a suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

The following question popped up in the suggested edits alert on my Stack Overflow menu bar:

> [How to read raw data stored in LPT1 Buffer memory?`C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874595/how-to-read-raw-data-stored-in-lpt1-buffer-memoryc-net)

The suggested edit awaiting approval was some code reformatting, but the post also had another problem which didn't get edited out (see below):

[image]

Should the edit have been rejected? Or should it be approved and then just go to the question and excise the offending line.

Would it be too mind-blowing (for approvers and the SO devs alike) to introduce a mechanism to edit the edit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen this a few times already.  I just approve the edit, then go in and make a new edit of my own.  That way I don't have to redo the work from the suggested edit.

To directly answer the question in your title though, I'd only reject an edit if it actively made a question worse.  Any improvement will be accepted (by me at least) then added to if necessary.

Comment: Should one be concerned about making the post CW due to too many editors?

Comment: @Hendrik: That is a valid concern, but I admit that I normally don't worry about it.  It takes five different editors to the body of a post (title and tag edits don't count, if I remember correctly) before it gets pushed into CW.  I'm usually the first or second editor, and most posts never see five.

Comment: Yep, 5 other editors, or 11 edits from the original author. [Title and tags do not count.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60923/which-edit-actions-can-move-a-post-into-community-wiki-mode/62673#62673)

Comment: @Bill If I understood you correctly, the giving points for correct edits simply doesn't make sense (though I know it is not a huge amount of points)

Comment: @Trufa: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Bill I'm sorry I misread the OP. My bad!

Comment: @Hendrik. Is this alerting you? (Sorry, Bill, testing for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78078/possible-bug-in-comment-replies-with-trailing-dots)

Answer (score 0):

In the example shown by you, the decision is completely on you to either accept or reject the edits. Reason being, the edits are only format changes and are not affecting the understandability or meaning of the asked question.

In other cases, usually if the edits tend to change the meaning of the question, you can reject them