# Should there be a delay before automatically making a post community wiki

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I've just been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727625/store-checkbox-value-in-an-array), which has been promoted to Community Wiki.  The original post was somewhat badly formatted, and attracted 7 edits within the first 5 minutes of it being posted (which I believe is what made it into a community wiki).  On the face of it, this seems to act against the purpose of making posts into Community Wiki's since the question isn't one that is likely to attract long term editing interest.

Should there be a grace period where the editors can go crazy fixing a post, before the edits start counting towards the post becomming a community wiki?  Even if the grace period was only the normal 5 minute editing grace given to the question asker, in this instance it would have made a difference.

EDIT:
Note, you can't look at the linked question anymore (at least I can't), because it's been deleted, but I think the question still stands.

Comment: I often wonder if the edit link should simply be disabled/hidden during the author's 5 minute grace period. But then I see really bad posts for which I'm quite sure the original author will not even try to fix it...

Comment: @Arjan: I wonder how this could happen since now [we thankfully have some prevention of edit clashes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts/28119#28119).

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant to Hendrik's question, but it was mostly a series of small edits (somebody correct the code formatting, somebody changed the title, somebody else changed a bit of text here, somebody changed a bit of text there, somebody else changed the title to something different).  At least one of the edits was from somebody with a rep of < 2K, so needed approval.

Comment: As an aside: it might be nice if a SO moderator could see if all edits in that deleted post kept previous edits in place. In other words: if no-one overwrote earlier changes, despite warnings, or due to not seeing warnings. Of course, the components like title, tags and body are all separate things, not yielding edit collisions if I am not mistaken. (ping @Hendrik)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind here: [Only body edits count toward CW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60923/which-edit-actions-can-move-a-post-into-community-wiki-mode/62673#62673).
Moreover, [this bug report by Arjan](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88186/collision-detection-fails-when-saving-while-suggested-edits-are-pending) might be relevant to the question.