# How to edit a post to fix formatting alone?

Tags: support, edits, markdown, whitespace

Say a user posts a question with a code block as follows:

function blah {

```
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
}
```

and I want to edit the post to fix the formatting to this:

```
function blah {
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
}
```

The edit is purely a whitespace edit, and since I'm only adding whitespace, will fail the validation of edits.

Is the inability to simply fix whitespace because I am as yet of insufficient rank, or is there some secret to fixing white space / formatting issues that I'm missing?

Comment: I'd say this is a rare situation - there's almost *always* something else in an unformatted code post that can be fixed. Spelling/grammar, title, something.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91807/why-isnt-a-format-only-edit-allowed

Comment: Perhaps, but it does happen from time to time and personally I'm only interested in fixing readability not proofreading someone else's bad grammar ;)

Comment: Then you will have to wait until you have enough rep to do this kind of edit. Usually doesn't take long for someone else to come along and fix it.

Comment: Ok so it is just a rep thing.  Thanks.

Comment: Incorrect formatting is a noticeable problem. There are questions/answers I find that are several months/years old that still have formatting issues. I'm with Greebo, it's terrible to try and read 50 lines of code that four spaces could fix in a second. I think only the most popular of questions are the ones that are quickly edited. This really should be something that could be opened to low level people. After all, just because we weren't here five years ago we still know what we're doing.