# Editing code blocks fails when I don't have editing permissions

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, edits

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why isn't a format-only edit allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91807/why-isnt-a-format-only-edit-allowed)
>   [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)

I just tried to fix two code blocks in a question by marking and clicking the "code sample"-button. But instead of the usual:

> This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

I got:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Edits must be at least 6 non-space characters; is there something else
>   to improve in this post?

Wouldn't it be better if code blocks weren't considered simple white space?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91807/why-isnt-a-format-only-edit-allowed

Comment: You really couldn't find anything else to fix? I'm not believing it.

Comment: IMO it shouldn't matter if there is anything else to fix. Sure, my edit might have just been one small improvement but it's better than nothing right? Sure this isn't just because code-formatting happens to be a case of inserting spaces, thus a technical issue, rather than an idelogical stand-point?

Comment: No, this is by design. Users without full editing privileges need to make edits that are more than 6 characters. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91753/low-rep-users-should-be-able-to-fix-broken-links

Comment: Very well, I don't agree with this decision since it feels a bit like ["you're holding it wrong"](http://www.engadget.com/2010/06/24/apple-responds-over-iphone-4-reception-issues-youre-holding-th/). But you're the boss(es) and I _can_ understand the issues with the queue.

Comment: @Popular Demand: I typed it myself, it says something like that for us users with insufficient rights to edit, and I didn't feel the exakt wording was important. Why do you ask?

Comment: Well, it's not quite the same as "you're holding it wrong", because the limit is eventually relaxed. Users with 2k+ reputation have full edit privileges across the site, no matter how trivial of edits they want to make. The reason we restrict users who are suggesting edits to non-trivial edits (more than 6 characters) is because those suggested edits require at least two high-rep users to view, decide, and process them. They're not completely free, but they're more than worth it for *substantial* edits. Agreed it's a bit of an edge case for code formatting, but 6 characters really isn't many..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a duplicate, but the answer for this was that if the code isn't properly formatted, there a probably more things wrong with the question you can fix (spelling, grammar, salutations, thanks, bad title).

Found the [dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters).

Comment: In this case I couldn't see anything obvious.

Comment: Could you post a link to the question?