# Have rollbacks not count towards community-wikiness

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-wiki, rollbacks

I think rollbacks shouldn't count towards posts [becoming Community Wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741).

If there is no change in content, the post was not generated by the community, but keeps being written by the original poster. If different users suggest and rollback edits, happen it twice and any single edit (e.g. to fix the issue) will make the post CW, for no justified reason.

*Strongly related* : [Does / should a rollback count as an edit toward community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89357/does-should-a-rollback-count-as-an-edit-toward-community-wiki), I assume (oh so lightly…) it's being one year without activity shows something of a consensus, so I upgrade the main tag. (Also, I feel like it didn't receive enough attention, but I lack the rep to drop a bounty and still keep commenting.)

<sub>Less related : [SO is too eager to turn my edited answers into Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/so-is-too-eager-to-turn-my-edited-answers-into-community-wiki). Status-declined, and many upvotes. I like the second most upvoted answer for the solutions it proposes.</sub>

Comment: Incessant rollbacks from the author of a post can sometimes be a sign of a bigger problem. This may or may not be related to the auto-wiki issue.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Ain't that what flags are for ? If it's meant to become an edit war anyway, I'm not sure becoming CW would prevent it.

Comment: Good point - we already have automatic flags in place for that. It would prevent someone from gaming votes with an edit war with himself though. But that may be too unlikely for it to matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is already the case, and [has been the case for a long time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60923/which-edit-actions-can-move-a-post-into-community-wiki-mode/62673#62673). I'd actually go as far as to say that rollbacks never counted for converting a post to Community Wiki. Seems like the kind of thing that would just be a matter of fact, rather than a deliberate (and unrequested) change some time before 2010.

Comment: Oh, that's great. I was fooled by fear and that other question you fixed by answering correctly. Thanks :·)