# Does retagging increment the edit count towards community wiki status?

Tags: feature-request, tags, community-wiki

#### Why I'm Asking

Based on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), it looks like questions are converted to community wikis when 5 different people edit the post. However, when you **retag** a question, it *also* shows as having been edited by the tagger.

#### What I'm Asking

It remains unclear to me whether retagging increments the edit count towards community wiki status. Does a retag count as an edit for this purpose?

#### Related Feature Request

If retagging counts as an edit, it probably shouldn't. Miscategorizations, or categorizations that change over time as tags (and tag usage) evolve, are not the same thing as active community maintenance of a living document.

If they are treated separately, it might be useful if retagging was shown as **retagged** rather than **edited** on the question. This would avoid confusion, and make the last action more obvious to people reading the question.

Comment: Your _question_ is answered [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62673).

Answer (score 2):

You're making several distinct suggestions, but I definitely agree with the suggestion to show 'retagged by ...' instead of 'edited by ...'. Now I often feel compelled to leave a comment saying that I retagged the question.

Comment: I agree that retagging should be shown separately. I mean, the retag feature even has its own access link and by using that you can't change the text of the post you're supposedly "editing".