# Why hasn't this question become a Community Wiki after 10 edits by the OP?

Tags: support, edits, specific-question, community-wiki

As per the [Community Wiki FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/187824):

> Posts enter community wiki mode when...
>
> - The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.

I am just curious to know why [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99077/187824) hasn't become Community Wiki after being edited more than 10 times by the OP? Looking at its [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/99077/revisions), that question has been edited 14 times by OP.

<sub>PS: I don't want to force that question to be a Community Wiki, but just want to report whether it is bug or not.</sub>

Comment: Someone probably flagged it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which edit actions can move a post into Community Wiki mode?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60923/which-edit-actions-can-move-a-post-into-community-wiki-mode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It *was* converted to Community Wiki automatically.

Then a moderator removed the CW status.

From [the FAQ you linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741):

> #### How can the Community Wiki status be removed from a post?
>
> Moderators can remove it, when necessary. Once removed, the post will never be given the CW status automatically due to a high number of edits again.

In this case, the removal of CW status was done in response to a flag from a third user who observed the conversion and felt it unwarranted.

Comment: +1 for very fast reply Shog :)

Comment: Very fast and with enough reference..

Comment: But normally we can see something like `post made Community Wiki by XYZ` [like here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/114354/revisions) But it is not available in this question's [revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/99077/revisions).

Comment: @hims056: When CW gets removed, it currently just destroys the references to it in the history. All the more reason to have the "Community Wiki removed" notice added to the revision history. :P

Comment: Just look at [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173659/187824). It is edited by the answerer [10 times](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/173659/revisions) (including 1st revision) but still it hasn't become CW. Doesn't first revision count? In other words does 10 edits mean "10 edit *after* the first revision"? (I commented this just after it was edited 10th time so not flag-unwiki this time)

Comment: 10 edits == 11 history entries, @hims056

Comment: @Shog9 - Okay thanks.

Comment: You've just saved my (SO) life, LOL. Thanks for that. -- That's because I just wanted to ask a question what would happen if you got the status converted back to normal by a mod, and decide to re-edit it after a while. Again, memorize this: __Once removed, the post will never be given the CW status automatically (...) again__. This is wonderful. Should that pointless and troublesome CW stuff get removed for good in future, you will only get two words from me: *Good riddance*. :P

Answer (score 5):

To complete the [story](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172105/165773), when I noticed that CW on that question has been auto-triggered by amount of revisions, I flagged it for moderator attention (that happened on Feb 18). Soon after that, my flag has been marked helpful and CW status was removed.

- For the record, flag message was as follows:

  > please take a look at revisions made to this question (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/99077/revisions) to consider whether automatic CW status triggered by "editing at least 10 times" is fair in this case. Per my reading of revisions diffs, all the edits so far were meaningful, relevant and justified by substantial effort at OP side

---

Note by the way that flagging isn't the only option when you feel auto-CW was wrong. Another option is to post on meta (examples at Programmers meta: [1](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3527/31260), [2](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5496/31260)).

The option I choose is mostly determined by whether I feel a "fairness" can be determined on formal / generic grounds or it requires some content / domain analysis. I do not want to burden moderator with content analysis: that's when I post to meta, so that moderator can make their decision based on community evaluation.

That particular case has fallen into rather formal grounds. Diffs I studied prior to flagging indicated that wast majority of revisions took several days of OP effort (*"...for 8 days now", "...for 10 days now"* - stuff like that) - note *"substantial"* in flag message. Per my reading, no amount of special / domain knowledge was required to decide whether CW is fair or not, which is why I used flag.