# Automatic community-wiki-ing of answers not consistent?

Tags: bug, community-wiki, specific-answer

It appears to me that there is a single answer to this question that is not community wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218429/1858225

All the other questions' edit histories (or at least, the ones I checked) say that they were automatically made community wikis when the question received 30 answers. But the edit history for the above answer doesn't mention anything about it ever having been a community wiki. Why is this?

(I'm marking this with the "bug" tag simply because I suspect it **might** be a bug, though I realize that this might be the desired behavior even though I don't understand it.)

Comment: I would say the answer for this question will be same as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172105/187824). Looks like a moderator has removed the CW status.

Comment: Also clearing your doubt related to revision history: I had the [same doubt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172104/why-hasnt-this-question-become-a-community-wiki-after-10-edits-by-the-op/172105#comment-510283) and  [@animuson's reply](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172104/why-hasnt-this-question-become-a-community-wiki-after-10-edits-by-the-op/172105#comment-510284) solved my doubt. & +1 for you profile pic :).

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the links; sorry I didn't see that question before posting. I like the suggestion of having "removed community wiki" show up in the edit history; any chance that that will ever happen? Any idea why it currently doesn't?

Comment: No idea. Perhaps we may ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the answer appears to be here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172105/218334

However, it looks like the failure to record the transition to and from community wiki status may still be a bug, so I'm opening a new question about it here:
[Conversion to/from Community Wiki not showing up in edit history for some answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177837/218334)