# Conversion to/from Community Wiki not showing up in edit history for some answers

Tags: bug, answers, community-wiki, revisions-list

It appears that for some answers that have been automatically converted to community wikis and then **reverted**, nothing in the edit history shows that the answer **was ever** a community wiki.

The case described in this previous meta question looks like an example: [Why is the conversion to Community Wiki not in the edit history for this question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68048/218334)

The case described in this previous meta question is **definitely** an example: [Automatic community-wiki-ing of answers not consistent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177736/218334)