# Would like to update answer, but it has 9 edits already

Tags: discussion, edits, community-wiki

I would like to update [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244402/57611) to add some new information. (I realized that when "walking the clustered index" of a table that has a multi-column clustered index, in most cases a great simplification can be achieved by using `WITH TIES` in the update statement to enable working only with the *first* column of the clustered index. I'd also like to change a couple of other minor things.)

However, if I make this update, I'll hit 10 updates, and the answer will get converted to community wiki. I hate asking moderators to remove community wiki status--it seems like a waste of their time. At the same time, it bugs me that my answer is not as good as it could be! And yes, it bugs me to lose the reputation if it goes community wiki.

Note that I am doing my best to make more substantial edits and fewer trivial ones, so I don't run into this limit as often. But it does happen sometimes. You can look at the answer history to see if you think that my 8 edits were excessive or not.

Should I:

1. Avoid making the edit,
2. Make the edit in pursuit of having the best answer and just take my lumps so I don't inconvenience moderators,
3. Or make the edit and flag for a moderator as it's not that big a deal for them?

Comment: FWIW, it has *eight* edits. The auto-CW wouldn't kick in until revision 11, which would be ten edits after the original answer was posted.

Comment: do you have a question? Seems like it's more trouble for all of meta to read this, and possibly a mod to volunteer to unwiki you, than just to flag and ask for an unwiki. But anyway, what's the question?

Comment: 10 *edits* is not the same as 10 *revisions*. The original post counts as the first *revision*, while the second revision is the first *edit*.

Comment: FWIW, this 10 edit auto-wiki limit is also the reason why I've stopped maintaining [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8391601/revisions). Instead, my last edit was to drop a link to my github where I can update it all I want. It's not close to 10 yet, but it will get there very quickly if I kept it up to date.

Comment: @GrantWinney It was primarily added to prevent people from repeatedly editing a question just to bump it on the active list and thus get more attention.

Comment: @Mysticial: Just take the plunge, then flag for moderator attention and have the CW status reverted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters isn't this somewhat a ... leap of faith?

Comment: @Mysticial See my answer. Those are substantial edits on your post too.

Comment: @JanDvorak: It has happened to me 2 or 3 times before, and every time the request was honoured, quite quickly.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Ah. That's reassuring. I'll keep that in mind for when the time comes.

Comment: related: [Why hasn't this question become a Community Wiki after 10 edits by the OP?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172104/why-hasnt-this-question-become-a-community-wiki-after-10-edits-by-the-op) "It was converted... the removal of CW status was done in response to a flag from a third user who observed the conversion and felt it unwarranted."

Comment: Related: [Can we disable automatic community wiki conversion for answer edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203616)

Comment: @GrantWinney: See [Why does repeated editing by same user lead to community wiki?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179901)

Comment: @KateGregory Just for you I added a real question. Though I think most people understood what I was asking. But as for asking "all of meta", do you not see value in community members checking themselves from potentially frowned-on behavior and *asking*? Or should we all just do what we think is best and care not what the community says?

Comment: @animuson You are absolutely right... I missed that (though in my question text, I did say 8--funny I didn't catch it at the time)

Comment: I made [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20431907/revisions) perfect on the 10th revision, lucky me

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're making substantial edits over a long period of time, you can just flag for a moderator to de-wikify your post after you hit the limit.  The auto-wiki is meant to discourage people from making insignificant edits every day to bump their post, milking it for more reputation/attention.  Since *most* of your revisions were substantial, and they were over a period of six months, you should be fine asking a moderator to reverse the wikification of this post when it happens.

Comment: Perhaps, after a thread reaching the limit of 10 edits and consequently, having a moderator "de-wikifyed" it the thread's author would win more clear 10 edits (or 5...).

Comment: @AndreSilva that sounds like a feature request... [maybe you should check this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203616/213575)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I appreciate your letting me know what you think is the best thing to do.