# Why wasn't this post auto-converted to Community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/612178/2024761) was edited by more than 5 different users apart from the OP but despite that, it wasn't converted to Community wiki? Why is that so?

I did go through [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/216721) and it clarifies that(emphasis mine)

> Posts enter community wiki mode when one of the following happens:
>
> - The body of the post has been edited by at least five (5) different users.
> - **The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.**

And it also states that

> - Rollbacks do not reverse any of the Community Wiki mode calculations.

Despite satisfying all the conditions, why wasn't the above linked question converted to community-wiki? Is it a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or is there something else to it which I seem to be missing?

Comment: Eight edits in half an hour by seven different users. Wow.

Comment: Maybe rollbacks/tag edits aren't countable edits?

Comment: @JeffMercado I know the actual *rollback* event is not counted as an edit (and it's actually listed as "rollback" rather than "edit" in the mod timeline). I'm not sure if tag-only edits count, though. It would make sense that they didn't, considering back then "retag" was a separate privilege.

Comment: But the answer which is there on meta said that *Rollbacks do not reverse any of the Community Wiki mode calculations*. And if that is applicable, then without the re-tags also, its more than 5 I guess. Also, I'm not sure if anything changed as in the answer I linked there was note saying *note that the rules outlined above are based on observations; the actual behavior of SO is subject to change without notice, and may well have done so since this was last updated...*

Comment: @R.J They don't *reverse* the count. As in, the edit before it still counts towards the wikification, and a rollback does not reverse wikification if it already occurred. The rollback itself does not count as an edit.

Comment: @animuson - Ah! That makes things a bit more clearer. Do you mind making this an answer? I am assuming that tag edits also(even at that time) did not count towards the CW count right?

Comment: Ah, found [a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60923/which-edit-actions-can-move-a-post-into-community-wiki-mode). I'll edit that information into the FAQ to make that rule more clear.

Comment: That would be great! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60923/which-edit-actions-can-move-a-post-into-community-wiki-mode) that I stumbled upon, only edits to the actual body of the post will count towards auto-wikification of a post. Edits to the title and tags, as well as rollbacks, will not affect it at all.

So, looking through the revision history with that in mind:

```
Revision   Auto-Wiki Count   Comment
-------------------------------------------------------------
1          0                 Original Post
2          0                 Didn't Edit Body
3          1                 New User Edited: GEOCHET
4          2                 New User Edited: Dana
5          2                 Didn't Edit Body
6          2                 Rollback
7          3                 New User Edited: George Stocker
8          4                 New User Edited: Ólafur Waage
9          4                 Rollback
```

So, currently only four different users other than the OP have "edited" the post, so it doesn't qualify for automatic wikification.

**Notes:** Of course, this is by our *current* standards for auto-wiki. According to the history of that FAQ, it was originally four users, and then changed to six edits by four users, then changing to five users. Who knows what the actual rules were way back in March of 2009, or if the system even worked correctly way back when. I also didn't include Gabrielle's recent edit because I don't know exactly what he did.

Presumably another body edit would knock that question into community wiki, although I don't encourage anyone to do that just for the sake of seeing if it does.

Comment: I think Gabrielle removed the security tag and re-added it, with the assumption that it was done within the grace period(guessing from the edit comment).