# Show remaining requirements to receive badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge progress reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports)

Since the badges help reinforce good behavior I think it'd be useful to show on the badges page what remaining requirements one has to receive a particular badge.

For instance, I've cleaned up a number of questions by editing, and I could swear I've hit 100, but no Strunk & White badge...why not tell me how many more edits I have left to go before receiving the badge?

Comment: For a lot of them the information is already available in some manner, but it would be kind of nice to have it consolidated in one place.

Comment: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/5117/how-many-edits-until-strunk-white?UserId=21441

Answer (score 2):

Many fear that in most cases, showing the remaining requirements or 'countdown' to a badge is like dangling the carrot. That's fine if you want someone to do a simple menial task like crawl or walk.

When it comes to tasks that require more thinking, its probably better if people knew 'the carrot is out there', else they may do things of lesser quality than normal just to get the reward.

Also, remember, there is a slight lag in badges being awarded.

Comment: +1 for the lag. It also varies from badge to badge, so you might not get the badge until a day after hitting the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are several dupes of this question for specific badges, such as for [Strunk & White](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39215/how-do-i-estimate-strunk-white-progress). The [data explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) is good for this.

Comment: Although really cool, the data explorer is unlikely to be that helpful if you need up to the minute stats.

Comment: @womp, I think people understand the limits of the data explorer. Still, the data at the moment is June 10, I think that's pretty good (it is June 24 as I write this).