# Suggested Edit Diff missing data

Tags: bug, status-norepro, suggested-edits, diff

I was looking at a suggested edit to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39215/how-do-i-estimate-strunk-white-progress/54790#54790), and it seemed like the editor had dropped a few letters in this edit, but when I went to the Improve screen, they were there.

Here's the Diff screen of the Suggested Edit:

[image: Edit Diff]

And here's the Improve screen:

[image: Bad Diff Proof]

Comment: It's the question identifier that differs, could this be it? `5117`, `93835`. If not, then it's something _much_ more subtle, or, I'm stupid _and_ blind. And there's a straggling `o` in a couple of the revisions... I feel like I'm overlooking the actual problem here...

Comment: @Mrd, Yes, I hadn't noticed the different number, that would be another problem, but I'm referring to the `til-` that's missing on the end of the first line.

Comment: @MrD it's different because the user who edited forgot to edit the actual link, he just edited the description. I fixed that now..

Comment: I'm still too blind to see the problem here. *And* I have my glasses on.

Comment: @Matt, look at the end of the first colored line on each side.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, thanks, great edit.

Comment: I repro this in IE 9, but not in Chrome. So it looks to be browser-specific. Are you seeing it in IE 9 as well?

Comment: @Cody, Yep, IE9.

Comment: Is still an issue?