# Why haven't I got the "Copy Editor" badge yet?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Today I went through Meta Stack Overflow and found a [link which shows how many posts have we edited](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all&search=Andro%20Selva); it shows 513 edits. Also I believe that one has to do only 500 edits to obtain the "Copy Editor" badge. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may have edited that many posts, but not all edits count.  [See this question for a list of what is required for each badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions). In this case;

- Edits on deleted posts do not count
- Edits to your own posts do not count
- Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count

[This tool](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1024/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges?UserId=603744), which I think is still a little generous, IIRC, suggests you have made 453 qualifying edits, so you are still 47 edits from the badge. This is slightly out of date: see Nick's comment for the real information,

Comment: The tool shows [I have only 351 edits](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/5157/how-many-edits-have-I-made?UserId=447356), but I did get the Copy Editor badge.

Comment: So how do you answer Shadow Wizard's comment here

Comment: Keep your hair on – I've only just seen it. Perhaps that query isn't so accurate. [This one looks better](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1024/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges?UserId=447356). The low number in this case is probably because the data is out of date (it's from the monthly dump rather than being live.)

Comment: Yeah...that query isn't correct at all, the OP has 487 qualifying edits, he's almost there!

Comment: @Nick care to share your mine of data? :-)

Comment: @Shadow - not sure we expose that query anywhere...and I'm querying the live database, so no sharing of that.  The key point is the user has edited the *same* revision several times, and those don't count (e.g. 5 minute edits), we eliminate those dupes in the count.

Comment: @Nick thanks, that's useful information.

Comment: @Andro_Selva [My query](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39215/how-do-i-estimate-strunk-white-progress/106070#106070) is the most accurate you're going to get with the "old" data.  As Nick notes, you've made 35 edits since the last data dump.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You may be interested in the query I just linked.