# Badge System & Editing

Tags: support, edits, badges, edit-badges

I recently have gone over the required editing of 80 posts to get the badge "Strunk & White".

However, as of this time I haven't been awarded the badge. Is there a additional requirements for this badge, or do certain badges get awarded at certain time intervals, or are they moderated/approved before awarded?

Or is it simply an error?

Just curious to understand how it works behind the scenes.

Comment: When I earned it it took a couple hours to show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> or do certain badges get awarded at certain time intervals

This is probably it. When was the last edit you made (the one that should've gotten you the badge)?

Comment: About 45 minutes ago.

Comment: I'd give it a little more time

Answer (score 3):

Not every edit counts towards these editing badges. For example look here to estimate your badge progress and find out what does and what does not count:

[How do I estimate Strunk & White progress?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106070/166308)

Comment: It says on my Review page though that I've made 90, and 112% done?

Comment: @Brian, on your "review" page? What's that? What does tell you the query I posted in the link? 1) be sure to use Matthew Read's query, because the other query is wrong! 2) this query is for stackoverflow only.

Comment: it clicked in must have been timed

Comment: @TomasT. I think he means as in http://stackoverflow.com/review

Comment: @Brian, maybe my english is not so good but I can neither understand nor even parse your last comment...

Comment: Sorry Tomas, it must have been a badge thats awarded on a timed interval, as I just got the badge a little over an hour ago, without doing anything extra.