# Discrepancy in the number of edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)

Is there any reason the Copy Editor badge doesn't report *all* my edits?

[image]

And this is a screenshot from a recent *suggested edit* page:

[image]

So 277 vs 291?

Comment: Did you make 14 edits in less than a day? And also, `291-9 = 282` might not help either.

Comment: BTW, can you give us a link to the place you took your first picture? I never knew about this...

Comment: @muntoo It's possible I might have, I've been spending an obscene amount time on SO lately so I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @muntoo: That appears on the right side of the [review panel](http://stackoverflow.com/review) (unless you have it already).

Comment: @animuson Already have it. I suppose I shouldn't be too sad. *\*Sob.\** :(

Comment: I don't remember 100% for sure, but I'm pretty sure the number for badge progress is cached, and only updates when the check to see if you've gained the badge is run.

Comment: @animuson The weird part is that the badge counter updates just fine. For example, I just got another edit approved and both the counters increased as they should.

Comment: @Marvin: [Here you go.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges) - The missing edits probably fall under one of the categories that don't count, in Jeff's answer. Most likely you made some edits which only retagged the question.

Comment: @animuson Hmm.. possibly. There's no way I'm going back into my edit history to verify this so that sounds like a good enough answer to me. Losing 14 edits isn't a big deal, I was more curious than anything. Care to post that as the answer?

Comment: My query here might help you determine which of your edits aren't being counted if you modify it to return ones that aren't in the edit types it uses: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106070/154510

Comment: @MatthewRead Another weird thing is that I can't seem to run SEDE queries for my user ID. Probably has something to do with not being here that long.. who knows.

Comment: Ah yes, the data dump is only every month or two so new new users won't see anything.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I wish there was a query that listed all the edits you've made and whether they counted or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to all of the above in the comments (e.g., perhaps there was a situation where you only edited the tags on the post), there are times where, despite yours being a great edit, the question is just too far off topic and ends up closed and deleted.  Unfortunately, edits on deleted posts do not count towards the Copy Editor badge.

Also, I believe edits will not count if you have edited the same post twice for some reason.