# Should I not receive Strunk & White badge?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edit-badges

When I saw my edits statistics there was written that I have 111 edits approved.

[image]

Why I didn't receive "Strunk & White" badge if required value is 80 edited post and I have 111 edits?

Comment: Tag only edits are not counted.

Comment: @Oded how can i get a number o counting edits

Comment: There is no direct way, as far as I know - you can go through the list of [your suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1952862/ty221?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and count those that apply.

Comment: [How do I estimate Strunk & White progress?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39215)

Comment: Go to Review, open [First Posts] or [Late Answers]. There you can see green progress bar with number of reviews performed. Hover over the bar or click on it and Badge Progress window will open. I think [Strunk & White] progress should be displayed there.