# How many posts have I edited so far?

Tags: support, edits, stack-exchange, personal-statistics

How can I know how many questions/answers I have edited so far for a specific Stackexchange site?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the new redesign of the [Users Page](https://superuser.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all), you can now see the number of edits users have made (I believe this includes both edits and retags).

If you need more detailed information, you can write a [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) query to find out -- now that the PostHistory table is included in the data, what you want can be found out exactly. (At this time, however, I don't know of a query which correctly does the calculation.)

**EDIT:** Turns out I got impatient and wrote a SEDE query myself! https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1397

Comment: Is this up to date? I get `1` for my stackoverflow accout, which is surelly less than I have.

Comment: @TomášZato SEDE is updated about every week

Answer (score 3):

There are SEDE queries that **almost**<sup>*</sup> do what you want. I put one together — as a learning exercise; it's probably not very efficient — based on some earlier queries, it's available at

http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges

<sup>*</sup> SEDE queries are imperfect because they only make the last editor's information available. So, if you edit a question and then someone else edits it some more, you won't get credit for that edit. They also assume that you get credit for both question edits and answer edits, which [I'm not sure is true](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges).