# What are the requirements for the Copy Editor badge?

Tags: discussion, edits, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Copy Editor's badge description says "edited 600 entries." Does it mean any edit — i.e. does editing your own comments, questions and posts count — or does it only include things like formatting someone else's posts?

Also, is there a way to track progress?

Comment: I offered a bounty on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges) after updating it, but got no response.

Comment: AFAIK, Copy Editor is just a higher level Strunk & White. Same actions, just more of them.

Comment: I know a progress tracker has been discussed many times, but I can't find the authoritative link right now. The answer is always no, because only the last edit is shown in the publicly available info, and all edits count for badge progress. Here's a fairly inaccurate approximation: http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges For reference, it says I need about 440 more edits for Copy Editor, but I earned Copy Editor yesterday.

Comment: @Jon, well, yes. So what are the requirements for Strunk & White?

Comment: @Pop: See Jeff's answer in that question...?

Comment: @Popular They're detailed in Jeff's answer. CW status has always been irrelevant to badges, and "post" means it's for both questions and answers. As far as the new items for new mechanics, tag wikis get their own badge and comment edits do not count.

Comment: @Jon, Jeff answered that question before it was expanded will all those shiny new bullet points, so his answer is incomplete. While I'm sure Grace is right, it'd be nice if the answer were updated.

Comment: @Pop Should I just toss everything into Jeff's answer, then?

Comment: @Pop: I think he left his answer because there was nothing to add. Out of the edited-in questions, the only two I can see needing an explicit answer are the ones about CW and tag wiki. I'm tempted to edit his answer (commenting on his answers rarely draw attention) with our assumptions and see if he fixes it, or leaves it.

Comment: Go for it, either of you (@Grace @Jon). _I am not responsible from any banning that results from going for it._

Answer (score 4):

Try going here:

http://odata.stackexchange.com/metasuperuser/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges

and entering your userid which is the number displayed in the address bar while viewing your profile.  This number is your userid in the stack overflow databases. Your user id being **305644** from Stack Overflow.

The real limitation to this is that the database is only "dumped" data and is not "live" data.

Comment: You can get the Editor badge for an edit to your own post. I don't think this query checks for that.

Comment: Perhaps it does not, I was hoping it was at least a lead for the op.

Comment: I wrote that query, and it's not very good. See the discussion above, especially "For reference, it says I need about 440 more edits for Copy Editor, but I earned Copy Editor yesterday." More explanation [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65542/how-many-posts-have-i-edited-so-far/65555#65555).

Comment: Awesome, or not so awesome - but nice involvement.

Comment: [My query for Copy Editor progress](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39215/how-do-i-estimate-strunk-white-progress/106070#106070) is pretty accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Editing your own questions and answers does not count towards the Copy Editor (or Strunk & White) badge.  Nor does editing your comments.  For it to count, you have to have edited someone else's question or answer.

Are you suspicious that you should not not have received your Copy Editor badge?  It is a hard-earned badge unless you game the system.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about my own progress on Meta, so I created a SEDE query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1397/how-many-copy-editor-strunk-white-qualifying-edits-have-i-made

The results from this query are identical to the real database query (I realized I have access to the actual query after starting on my own). All the required data to get an exact result is available through SEDE (we no longer need to estimate as in Michael's query, which served its purpose at the time).

Note: Copy Editor is **exactly** the same as Strunk & White except with a higher threshold.