# I cannot find how many post I edited

Tags: support, edits, personal-statistics

I'm curious about how many answers & questions I've edited, and wondering why there is no integrated counter in the SO website!
I searched and found many previous Q&As like: [How many posts have I edited so far?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65542/how-many-posts-have-i-edited-so-far)
but when I try to find my counter, I don't get any data!

E.g: I used the [progress-towards-editor-badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/10950/progress-towards-editor-badges) query, but this is the result I got after entering my ID `1358670`:

```
Edits needed to earn Editor badge Edits needed to earn Strunk & White badge Edits needed to earn Copy Editor badge 
--------------------------------- ----------------------------------------- -------------------------------------- 
1                                 100                                       600                                    

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Does anybody have an idea? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong!

Comment: Just a friendly tip for the future: Consider using less exclamation points (!) in your text. It looks like you're shouting, or you're angry (I realise neither of those are actually true, but appearances do matter). Just type in a calm, sedate manner. =)

Comment: Great remark @J.Steen many thanks I never thought this could mean being angry :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its returning correct result because it returns counts of the number of title and/or body revisions you've made on other people's **non-deleted posts**.

[You can verify here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/35999/how-many-copy-editor-strunk-white-qualifying-edits-have-i-made)

Comment: I haven't really understand why it should give me 0 edits, I'm pretty sure I edited many posts, and the solution [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91878/where-can-i-see-how-many-posts-have-i-edited) worked for me now and gave 6 edits while queries still gave me 0, which one of them is correct ? and which one is counted in rewarding badges ?

Comment: as I written queries result is for non-deleted post may be u edited the post gets deleted

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae the data in Data Explorer is old, I think that at least a month so you won't see any new edits you make.

Comment: hum... but I can still see the posts I edited ! like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155809/unexpected-numbers-css-behaviour-jqm)