# Bug in Editor badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

Maybe it's just a one-off.  [**One SF user**](https://serverfault.com/users/5144/peter-mortensen) currently with 392 rep has earned all 3 editor badges.  I can overlook Editor, a little less willing for Strunk & White, but Copy Editor?  Even with edit approvals in place that seems like a stretch.

[**This query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges) on Odata even says 211 edits left.
[**This one**](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/s/335/my-edits-sw-and-copy-editor) says 211 as well (600-389).

Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Don't both of those queries use the LastEditor field, which isn't exactly accurate for the badge?

Comment: @Grace: yes, good point.  Still...  Just seemed odd that such a low rep user on SF would have that many edits.  But again, I could just be off base!

Comment: Actually... [you're not the first to try and report Peter Mortenson's SF account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71566/how-does-a-user-edit-posts-when-they-are-below-the-edit-other-peoples-posts-th). He's very, very prolific in his edits, and thanks to Community Wiki he actually had this badge loooong before the suggested edits system.

Comment: @Grace: Ah, yes.  CW... duh.  Post that as an answer and I'll accept, and we can also close as a dupe of Pekka's question.

Comment: I'm normally fairly hesitant about leaving an answer to a question that I have voted to close as a duplicate, especially since my answer (deleted, already) is pretty much the same as Pekka's, just a bit more elaborate and theatrical.

Comment: @squillman going through the activity history every edit I clicked on was for a Community Wiki post.  However [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges) states that CW edits are not eligible...?  There are also a number of minor repeat edits on the same posts.

Comment: @Grace fair enough!

Comment: @dave The "CW doesn't count" was a guess that was edited in, not an official statement, complete with a "rollback if I'm wrong" edit summary. I've always myself stated that CW edits do count, because Community Wiki status hasn't directly affected badges.

Comment: @Grace Note ok, good to know.  I guess this case proves they do count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This odata query satisfies me that it's not a bug:

```
select count(*)
from PostHistory
where userid=5144
and posthistorytypeid in (4,5,7,8)
```

Assuming that CW edits count toward the total.