# Not getting edit's +2 rep after reaching 2k rep

Tags: support, reputation, edits

After reaching 2k rep , I'm not receiving  +2 rep per edit. Why?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

> The other way to gain reputation is by **suggesting edits** to existing posts as a **new** registered user. Each edit will be peer reviewed, and if it is accepted, you will earn +2 reputation. You can only earn a maximum of +1000 total reputation through suggested edits, however.

Given you hit 2000, you **lost** the ability to **suggest** an edit, so that no longer applies, because you earned this one

> 2000   Edit* other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits

* *Without suggesting. Yes you read right, you can now edit away at will without awaiting approval.*

Answer (score 12):

You receive 2 rep points per *approval* of your edits (up to 1,000 points). Once you have 2,000 reputation, your edits are no longer held for approval and there are no more reputation rewards as a result.

Answer (score 9):

This seems fine to me. By the time you've got that level of reputation, you're already engaged with the site, and probably making corrections as needed. If editing is really your thing, you can go for the [editor badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges).

(And you still do get +2 for accepted tag wiki edits.)

Comment: Of course you only get +2 for accepted tag wiki edits until you hit 20k rep and don't have to get your wiki edits reviewed! :)

Comment: @Gabe: oh, the hard life of the 20k users. :)

Comment: The only think harder than being a 20k user is being a mod. I'm so glad I'm not a mod!

Comment: @Gabe Or until you hit 1000 reputation earned from suggested edits.