# Why did I stop getting reputation for editing posts when I reached 2000 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not getting edit's +2 rep after reaching 2k rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85229/not-getting-edits-2-rep-after-reaching-2k-rep)

I just reached 2000 rep in SO. But, I noticed that I stopped getting reputation for editing posts. Why is that? I have been browsing around and can't find any reference to this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only gain reputation from suggested edits, not from direct edits.

When you had less than 2000 reputation, your edits were *suggested* edits, and needed to be approved by 2 users with 2000+ reputation.

Now that you have 2000 reputation, your edits take effect immediately, with no action required by other users.

From the faq link:

> The other way to gain reputation is by
>   suggesting edits to existing posts as
>   a new registered user. Each edit will
>   be peer reviewed, and if it is
>   accepted, you will earn +2 reputation.

I admit it isn't very clear, but it does have the word "new" in the description.  Now that you have reached 2000 rep, you no longer meet this definition of a new user.