# Users who gained over 2000 rep will not get rep from edit question or answer?

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not getting edit's +2 rep after reaching 2k rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85229/not-getting-edits-2-rep-after-reaching-2k-rep)

The FAQ didn't describe it.

If yes, How Stack Overflow encourage users (with 2000+ rep) to improve Q&A?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes that is true. From 2000 onwards there is no reputation gain through edits.

People that are dedicated enough will edit posts anyway because they want to improve the overall quality. I have never edited because of the reputation, in fact that didn't even exist until I got to 2000.

It is just about the dedication to maintain the site and make it the best place it can be.

Comment: The 2k rept isn't the strict limit on getting rep from suggested edits, it's simply that at 2K you stop being able to suggest edits on normal posts - you can see get +2 rep for suggesting edits to tag wikis (up to the 1000 limit or being able to edit tag wikis directly, of course)

Comment: @DMA57361 I have known this rule. And I just want to know the rule that direct edit by users who have 2000+ rep

Comment: Note however you can get a nice [golden badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/65/copy-editor) when you edit 500 posts.