# Do users with 2,000+ rep get +2 on edits

Tags: support, reputation, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

I see that you get +2 if you are the edit suggester and it is approved however, my question is since people with 2,000+ rep can edit posts do they get +2? I am assuming that if you have 2,000 rep then your edits do not need to be approved, (hence my questions).

Comment: Good question.  I would have thought that you could, as long as you hadn't hit the rep-from-edits-limit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), [Not getting edit's +2 rep after reaching 2k rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85229/not-getting-edits-2-rep-after-reaching-2k-rep), [Users who gained over 2000 rep will not get rep from edit question or answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95221/users-who-gained-over-2000-rep-will-not-get-rep-from-edit-question-or-answer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can still gain +2 reputation on suggested edits to tag wikis and their excerpts, but you are no longer able to receive the +2 on regular suggested edits on answers and questions because you now have full edit privileges on those (and don't need your edits approved).

Keep in mind that once you hit 20,000 reputation, you'll also gain [full edit privileges on tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) and will no longer be eligible for +2 on those either.

Comment: It must be really hard to realize that you won't be able to get these nice +2 anymore once you reach 20000 :(

Comment: @talnicolas: It's cool, I'm not even at 10k yet. There's plenty of time. And I've already gotten 20 reputation from suggested edits! That's 0.01% progress! I'll get there!

Comment: ;) keep up the good work!

Comment: I'm tempted to try to get the rest of the way to 2k just by editing... (but not too tempted)

Comment: If you're looking for some easy editing rep, [I've got a great suggestion for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119963/164291) (:

Comment: @Phoenix: [Just for you.](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/208180) :)