# Where's my Strunk & White badge?

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)

According to other questions on here, only edits to other users' posts count.

I have 144 edits according to https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all and there are not 64 of them that are edits to my own posts.

Is there something else that triggers the [Strunk & White](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) badge?

---

I made some more edits none of which were tags, my own posts, or re-edits, and I am now up to "164 edits."

Still no badge.

---

Okay, I got the badge!  I guess it took a little while to filter through the system.

Comment: Also they need to be edit to different posts, so you could have made 80 edits, but if you've edited a number of posts twice (or more) they won't count.

Comment: @ChrisF  That probably explains it right there, thank you.

Comment: Yep now you have exactly 80 edit suggestions approved - hope you'll keep editing even though you got the badge! ;)

Comment: @Shadow Probably not quite at the same rate but yes I will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, according to this:
[image: Mr. Wizard edit suggestions]

You still need 18 edit suggestion approved (or "real" edits once you hit 2K rep) before you get the badge.

Why the difference between this and your profile activity? I guess that when you just edit tags it doesn't count, only when you edit the post body.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I can hardly believe that only 62 of my 144 edits have been to posts not my own.  The 144 is not counting comment edits, is it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - comment edits are not counted anywhere afaik. The 144 are all edits done on posts made by others, probably Chris is right though, when you make several edits on same post it does increase the total edit count (144) but it does not increase the "unique" edit count required for the badge.

Comment: how do I access the "Editor Stats" page? I can't find it on my profile.

Comment: @Andrea no direct link that I know of, I just went to one of his suggested edits revision page and it's there. In your case you can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/3792) (in the bottom) but it's not relevant any more as you can edit by yourself.. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers)

Check out progressbar. It will show you the correct number of Edits you have uptill now.

Comment: That's a new feature since I asked this question, and it's a good answer. +1