# Badge not received

Tags: support, edits, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)
>   [Where’s my Strunk & White badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85995/wheres-my-strunk-white-badge)

I have edited 82 post till now.As per the Badges list [description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=silver), if you edited 80 post then you should be awarded with a badge `Strunk & White`. But I haven't received it yet.

Comment: Did you edit 82 *unique* posts? Only one edit per post counts.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258. Edits on your own posts also don't count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have edited 80 *unique* posts that have not since been deleted, none of which can be your own.

Also, the badge is not handed out the moment your 80th edit has been accepted, badges are handed out with a batch process. It can take a few hours before you are awarded the badge.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.How would i know that how much unique post i have edited till now?

Comment: @AndroidLearner: The [review queue stats pages](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) give you a progress report (hover over the progress bar at the top). I believe you can already see that page (depends on your reputation).

Comment: Yes,It shows that i have edited the 82 post but it may take some time for process as you already mentioned. Thanks :)

Comment: i've got my badge.

Comment: Congratulations! :-)