# Does editing your own posts increase your edit count?

Tags: support, edits, edit-badges

My question is pretty straightforward... Does editing your own posts increase your edited posts count? I don't think so, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: See Jeff's answer on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, editing your own posts does not increase your "edit count" as used to determine eligibility for badges such as [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) or [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor).

Jeff gives the official answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges/445#445):

> - does not include edits to your own posts
> - does not include edits to tags
> - community-wiki posts are eligible
> - tag wiki posts are eligible
>
> only edits to title and body count towards the S&W/Copy Editor badges