# Is it possible to know the count of edits I made on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, badges, edits, editor, edit-badges

Is it possible to know the number of edits I made on Stack Overflow?

For example, is there a way to know our status towards reaching the [copy editor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) -> [Editors](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors) -> [All](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) -> <type part of your user name>.

This count includes edits to your own posts and edits to tags that [do not count toward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges/445#445) the [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) silver badge and the [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor) gold badge.

[image]

Comment: These numbers include edits you have made to your own posts, which do not count towards the badge.

Comment: @jonsca: yes, and retagging. [Retagging does not count towards the badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges/445#445) either.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/727473/deepu-s-nath?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_revisions

Answer (score 1):

Aside from counting your revisions of other's posts by hand (or using the http://data.stackexchange.com, e.g., [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1410/copy-editor-and-strunk-white-badges-progress)) you cannot tell how far along you are from the `Editors` tab because that number includes edits you have made to your own posts.

The count on that tab also doesn't include (approved) edits that you made prior to gaining 2000 rep, which do count towards Strunk and White anyway, I believe.

Comment: That query gives incorrect results because it includes all types of revisions. Use this one instead: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1397/how-many-copy-editor-strunk-white-qualifying-edits-have-i-made

Comment: @Jon Thanks, I think I grabbed for the wrong one (there's only like 10 different flavors of that one query! :) )

Answer (score 0):

Progress towards Copy Editor, and some other badges, is now displayed on the `/review` page. (Well, technically, it isn't there *right* now, because the team is beta-testing a new format for `/review`. But they've promised to bring it back soon.)