# Is the number of edits on the users page the one relevant for the edit badges?

Tags: support, edits, users-page, edit-badges

Is the number of edits at https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all the one that counts the edits relevant for gaining the *Strunk & White* and *Copy Editor* badges? (If not, wouldn't it be nice to have it that way? There's no reason for two different edit counts named the same.)

Comment: Currently we don't have any real "counter" for badge progress, and we won't have as Jeff want to keep some badges a "surprise".

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Thanks for the info. Does this mean Aziz's data.sx script isn't correct either?

Comment: The data dump is old (I think around a month) so it can never be really accurate..

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Actually, the latest dump isn't quite a week old. Apart from that, is the script correct for the date the data was dumped?

Comment: The most accurate script can be found [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1024/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges?UserId=447356) or in your case see [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/s/1024/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That appears to count multiple edits on the same post.  It's off by 34 for me on Android compared to [my method](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39215/how-do-i-estimate-strunk-white-progress/106070#106070).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to know the count of edits I made on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96457/is-it-possible-to-know-the-count-of-edits-i-made-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @MatthewRead thanks, yours show 550 edits for me while 557 in the other.. looks more accurate indeed then.

Comment: At some point, the team started displaying edit badge progress on the `/review` pages. It's not there _right_ now because they're beta testing a new `/review` system. They'll bring it back once testing is done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, they're not the same, for two reasons:

- The badge is intended to exclude specific (the trivial ones, mostly) edits, though there's no reason to exclude those counts for general recognition of those users on the `/users` page.
- Performance would *greatly* suffer if we had to do the same checks as the badge did for *all* users every time that query did a re-sort, so it's partially for performance as well.

Comment: Is it not possible that you could stick the result of the last check you did for the badge into a table somewhere and have that and a time stamp visible?

Comment: @awoodland - not performance-wise for nearly a million users...nope.

Answer (score 1):

No, the edit count shown on "Editors" tab could be different, I think it also includes "retags". To get an edit count that are eligible for "Strunk & White" badge, try running this query on data.stackexchange.com. Note, data.SE will not give you the latest count as the data is dumped every month:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT RevisionGUID)
FROM PostHistory
WHERE UserId = <YourUserId>
AND PostHistoryTypeId IN (4,5) -- 4 and 5 are post title and post body
```

"Strunk & White" is for those users who try to fix spellings and grammar of question titles and body.

Comment: I think you also need to take away self edits

Comment: And multiple edits on the same post don't count.  Check out [my query](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39215/how-do-i-estimate-strunk-white-progress/106070#106070), so far as I've been able to determine it's accurate on the data dump.