# Does editing only a question's title count towards the editor badges?

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)

I found that when I edit a question title only, with less than 6 characters change, it is considered as a valid edit.

Are such edits considered in the counts required to obtain badges like CopyEditor and Strunk and White?

Answer (score 2):

As per Jeff's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges/445#445):

> only edits to title and body count towards the S&W/Copy Editor badges

Though with the word `and` in there, I'm not totally sure if Title edits only count.