# Does editing only a question's title / a body count towards the editor badges?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)

there is a answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges/445#445) telling how to get S&W/Copy Editor  --> here is the answer

- does not include edits to your own posts
- does not include edits to tags
- community-wiki posts are eligible
- tag wiki posts are eligible
- only edits to title and body count

However, i would like to ask....
Does editing **the Title only** or **the body only** make a valid count? or it requires both?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105819/does-editing-only-a-questions-title-count-towards-the-editor-badges

Comment: @Mat: the reason i post this again because i can't get the answer and it was closed..

Comment: See Jeff's comment in the answer you linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Only edits to title and body count" doesn't mean that you need to edit both the title and the body of a question to be able to get the badge; it means that you don't get the badge if you just edit the question's tags.