# Is the edit count on the user's suggested-edits page the same used to determine Strunk & White and Copy Editor?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)

The bottom of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/120675) in the user section shows the number of approved and rejected edits by the user. Is this the same counter/number used to award the Strunk & White and Copy Editor badges? Or does it include edits that don't count towards the badges?

Comment: @lunboks Not quite the same. I'm asking if that specific counter counts the same edits that contribute to the editor badges, or if counts some that don't, or if doesn't count some that do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The counter there and the one for the badges are two independent concepts.

Strunk & White and Copy Editor can be earned by suggested edits. But they can also be earned by the normal edits you can perform on Community Wiki posts, or on any post when you hit 2000 reputation. Furthermore, the *rejected* edits don't count as edits because they are not committed into the system.

So, the number of `approved suggested edits` does contribute to getting those badges, but it is not necessarily the complete picture. It is also not necessarily accurate that all of those listed would count, as [the badges don't care about tag-only edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges). Suggested edits may include those which are tag only.