# Do retags count towards the number of edits for the "Strunk & White" badge?

Tags: support, tags, edits, edit-badges

The "Strunk & White" badge is received after editing 80 posts. According to this, I would like to ask a question. Do retags count? And where to check the total edit count?

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they don't. See [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions); from the `Strunk & White` entry:

> Perform a total of 500 edits between questions, answers and tag wikis
>
> - Edits on deleted posts do not count
> - Edits to your own posts do not count
> - Edits to CW posts do count
> - **Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count**
> - Tag wiki edits do count
> - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges do count, once approved

(emphasis mine).

You can use the [*old* review UI](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) to track your Strunk & White progress.