# Working toward "copy-editor" badge

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

As I often edit posts on SO, I started wondering about the "copy-editor" badge.  My profile shows "502 revisions", but didn't get the badge yet.  I started looking elsewhere and according to the "editors" page, I have made 305 edits:

[image]

Yet, when I look while in the review queue, the number shown is 296 edits:

[image]

Are these numbers coming from the same dataset? Which one is correct?

I have edited another post, which should count (body changes) and looked at the two numbers above - they haven't changed.  So, is the counting working correctly?

P.S. To pre-empt this question, I am *not* a badge chaser.  I use the site both for asking and answering questions; I don't consider badges a bragging thing and only consider them as a nice by-product of being active on the site.

Comment: The data within the data explorer is not a real-time updated dataset. It is some time behind. Last update was April 28 it seems.

Comment: Ok, that would make sense that. I'll re-run the query after some time to verify and will update the question or add a comment here after that.

Comment: @gnat It's not a duplicate at all.  I am not asking what edits count toward the badge.  I am asking why a specific edit, that should have counted, did not.

Comment: @Bart How do I check when the data was last updated?

Comment: It is mentioned on the front page of the data explorer.

Comment: @Bart,D'oh! Thanks. As I got to the data explorer via a direct link to a specific query, I didn't even look at the main page.  Thanks.

Comment: It says 305 on the [users/editors page](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all&search=aleks+g).

Comment: @ChrisF This question is not a duplicate.  I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You were looking at *revisions* (profile>activity>revisions), which include edits you have made to your own posts, [which don't count towards editor badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges).

You can see your edits (to other people's posts) count by searching for your name on the [users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all&search=aleks+g).

Comment: Revisions are NOT just edits made to my own posts, in fact, edits to my own posts are not shown their at all.

Comment: @AleksG they definitely include edits you've made to your own posts (or at least they do for me).

Comment: They definitely include all edits I have made to other posts

Comment: @AleksG agreed, I take back the earlier claim (and replace it with "include")!

Comment: The number displayed at that search doesn't necessarily reflect progress toward copy-editor; it includes edits to titles and tags. The badge progress number shown in OP's image is different.