# Why haven't I earned the badge, but I have it?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, badges, data-explorer

I saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178605/working-toward-copy-editor-badge), which discussed [a Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62091) for counting edits. So I decided to try it out with the account I am most active on, [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ssumner). To my surprise, the results were:

- User: SSumner
- Edit count: 65
- Edits needed to earn 'Editor' badge: 0
- Edits needed to earn 'Strunk & White' badge: 15
- Edits needed to earn 'Copy Editor' badge 435

But *I've already earned the Strunk & White Badge*, and when I look at the badge progress

[image]

I see I have made 113 edits (and I'm pretty sure they're the same edit types, as both are the ones supposed to count towards the badge)

I don't *think* this a duplicate of the question that prompted me to ask this, or a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges), because I am asking:

**Why have I been awarded the badge, when the data says I shouldn't have been**?

Comment: More likely, there's an error in the SEDE query

Answer (score 6):

The data in the Data Explorer is not up to date. It's dumped occasionally, and does not have live data.

You're seeing your edit count as of the last time the data in the Data Explorer was updated.

From the [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq):

> **How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**
>
> Data is updated monthly.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, because I've only made 2 edits to other people's posts in the past month

Comment: Oddly enough, SEDE says the last dump was Apr. 28, 3 days ago.

Comment: I haven't made any edits since that point

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the discrepancy is that the SEDE query is wrong. Disassociated posts have no user id. :-)

Comment: So do you mean that edits I've made to posts that were deleted or anonymous didn't show up in the query?

Comment: If a user is deleted, then there is only a user name but no user id associated with a post.

Comment: So disassociated posts don't show up in the query then?