# Is my reputation frozen?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits

Until this day, for each interaction with the SO Site, I received my reputation points at the same moment of the interaction. For example, when suggested edition was accepted, my reputation would increase by two points at the same moment.
It seems to me that my reputation stood today, even though I suggested edits and they were accepted.
Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: I believe you can only get a maximum of 1k rep from suggested edits. Could you have reached that cap?

Comment: The 1,000 point cap is documented here: [How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/191410)

Comment: Why it show's in the badge progress on the review page, that I have "only" 483 edit's?

Comment: @tsippert: Different criteria. Only one edit *per post* is counted, for example. See [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442)

Comment: @MartijnPieters got it ;) Thank's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have suggested a total of [594 edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2139775/tsippert?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Looking at [one suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2427885) you can see that:

> tsippert had 529 edit suggestions approved, and 89 edit suggestions rejected

There is a [cap of 1000 points reputation earned from accepted suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), and you hit that cap when 500 of your suggested edits were accepted:

> - you [suggest an edit and it is accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work): **+2** (up to a total of +1000 per user)

and from [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work):

> When a suggested edit is approved, the user who suggested it gets +2 reputation. The regular daily reputation cap applies, and the total cap is 1,000. Like any other reputation, the +2 is deleted if the edited post is ever deleted.

If anyone votes on your existing question or answers or you were to add more questions or answers and received votes on those, you would see that your reputation is not frozen.

Comment: He only has 528 accepted edits though, not 594.

Comment: @Servy: I included rejected edits. See the links included in my post.

Comment: I know you included both.  Rejected edits won't contribute to the 1000k rep from edits limit.  If he had 100 rejected edits he'd still be getting rep from posts.  The key point is the 500+ accepted edits.

Answer (score 11):

You have 528 edit suggestions approved.  There is a max of 1000 rep that can be gained from suggested edits; with that many approved suggestions you've passed that.

Comment: Why it show's in the badge progress on the review page, that I have "only" 483 edit's?

Comment: Yeesh. Six upvotes for multiplying by two. I wish I could do that.

Comment: @tsippert The badge is for edits on distinct posts.

Answer (score 6):

You can only receive a maximum of 1k rep from suggested edits. This info can be found as one of the bullets in [What is Reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)