# What Constitutes An Edit?

Tags: discussion, edits

While trollin around the review section, I noticed that I only have 38 edits. I'm very sure that I have edited more than 38 questions - so I was wondering if there is a certain criteria that needs to be met in order for it to count towards the badge?

Comment: Are you confusing edits with edits you've reviewed?

Comment: @codeMagic nope

Comment: The question has to survive as well.  An edit doesn't guarantee it isn't going to be deleted.  If it requires an edit then it is already on the endangered species list :)

Comment: Where exactly did you see the 38 edits figure? (I'd like to see what I'm at)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot under review, hover over any of the progress meters and you'll see progress on several ones

Comment: @RUJordan You are, in fact, confusing the number of edits with the number of reviews you have made. That statistics bar measures the number of suggested edits you have reviewed, not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have edited 38 distinct posts that did not belong to you and have not since been deleted.  Editing the same post more than once only adds one to that count, and deleted posts along with edits to your own posts are not included in that particular counter.

If you want to see all of the edits that you've made to non-deleted posts (outside of the grace period) that is visible in [your activity.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774078/rujordan?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

Comment: So, does editting just the tags on a question count? Does it have to be 6 characters or more? I knew my own questions do not count

Comment: @Servy Nope, [tag edits aren't counted in that measure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/445/237685).