# How did I get my Editor badge when I shouldn't have?

Tags: support, edits, badges

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges):

> *What is NOT included*
>
> - edits to your own posts

I am not supposed to get the Editor badge after editing my own post. However, recently I faced an issue with my post, and edited it. It was my first ever post (on that site), and my first ever edit. Now, for some reason, this appears on my reputation feed:

[image: Badge]

Now, this seems weird in two ways:

- I shouldn't have received this, as it was my own post.
- I don't even see the badge everywhere. On some pages, on certain times, it still shows me 1 bronze medal (whereas the Editor one would be my second one).

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/245360), that rule doesn't apply any more:

> - bronze; awarded once
> - Edit the title or body of any post

So the script is right awarding you that badge. I hope you enjoy it!

Comment: I have edited both the FAQ and the post you link to reflect the current badge rules.

Comment: Well, you edited the badge under "Area 51 badges", the actual badge is under "Moderation Badges" answer/section, where it says "Edit the title or body of any post".

Comment: Ouch. Hard to see. Thanks for noticing @sha