# Suggested next badge 'Editor' but no editing rights yet

Tags: discussion, support, badges, badge-progress

My current rep on Software Engineering Meta does not allow me to edit yet:

[image]

yet the suggested next badge is *Editor*:

[image]

I would not call this a 'bug' exactly, but it's a bit weird.
Can anything be done about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can earn the "Editor" badge by editing your own posts!

You can also [edit Community Wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges?rq=1).